# PDO prepare - preventing null value SQL update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have optional input provided as the 'type' value. I'm trying to prevent the statement from updating the type if it is null data and continue to update the equipment value.

Im tempted to create seperate prepare statements dependant on PHP check of null, but then found the SQL `ISNULL()`. I havnt used it before and am unsure how to use it within a prepare, unless there is a better way of achieving this?

**PHP:**

```
    $update = $db -> prepare("UPDATE room 
    SET type = ISNULL(@:type,:type), equipment = :equipment 
    WHERE room_id = :room_id");

    $update -> bindParam(":room_id", $room_id);
    $update -> bindParam(":type", $data['type']);
    $update -> bindParam(":equipment", $equipmentList);

    $update -> execute();
```

I get a 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582' when attempting the above.

**UPDATE:**

```
    UPDATE room 
    SET type = IFNULL(:type, type), equipment = :equipment 
    WHERE room_id = :room_id
```

Ok this correct syntax fixes errors, thanks to **eggyal**! The problem now is that null `:type` values are updated and the database value`type`(which is a enum) is not used instead of the null. I double checked in php before SQL that the :type values is null.

Why is `IFNULL` still returning a null?

Comment: Why don't you just check in PHP if it's null and if not - executed the statement, otherwise do nothing? Keep it simple, and it's simple if it's checked in PHP since it won't reach MySQL at all - therefore, it's even faster.

Answer (score 3):

- Use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`, you are not altering the **value** of parameter, therefore you don't need to pass it by reference.
- if the data type in MySQL **can contain null** then you can tell it that you are sending a `NULL` value. Code:

`$update -> bindValue(":type", $data['type'], is_null($data['type'] ? PDO::PARAM_NULL : PDO::PARAM_STR);`

If your target column **cannot contain null** then you do not need to execute the query at all.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's [`ISNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) function takes only a single argument and returns either 1 or 0 indicating whether that argument was null or not, respectively.  It is equivalent to the [`IS NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) comparison operator.

MySQL does have a 2-argument [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function, which may have been what you intended to use (though the arguments you've applied are nonsense)?

```sql
UPDATE room 
SET    type      = IFNULL(:type, type),
       equipment = :equipment 
WHERE  room_id   = :room_id
```

If `:type` is not `NULL`, its value will be used; else the incumbent value of the `type` column will be used instead (yielding no change).

Comment: It might still be important to have the *equipment* field updated.

Comment: I see..I got them mixed up, thanks you for the explaination, it helped alot! It is error free, but excepts null values now. The type value stored in database is a 'enum', would this affect the result somehow?

Comment: @Orbitall: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "*excepts null values now*"—please elaborate?

Comment: @Orbitall - why are you checking for `NULL` inside the query? You obviously don't want `NULL` in any form or way, your data type apparently won't even accept it. Why do you bother doing this check in SQL? It's trivial in php `if(empty($your_variable)) return false;` and job done, SQL's job is not to implement validation of your input.

Comment: @eggyal: The `IFNULL()` doesnt seem to be working as intended. The null value ':type' is used and not replaced with the current database value 'type'...Check update.

Comment: @Mjh: Well my orginal question asked "...unless there is a better way of achieving this?". I am trying out the 1st answer to my question assuming this is the best method. Are you suggesting that I should have multiple SQL statements dependant on null input? Would this be alot more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COALESCE()` function. It takes as many arguments as you give it and returns the first not-null argument it encounters if any. Otherwise it returns NULL.

```
UPDATE room 
SET type = COALESCE(:type, type), equipment = :equipment 
WHERE room_id = :room_id
```